# How to create a report 'List of bugs by PBI'

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

I would like to create a report with SQL Report Builder 2.0 and TFS 2010 that shows a list of bugs for each PBI.

Can anybody help me out with the MDX query? (preferably by using the query builder of Report Builder 2.0)
I've tried many things, none of them where a success.

We use the Scrum1.0 template and Microsoft Test Manager, so the work item hierarchy is like this:
PBI -> Test Case (link type: Tested By)
Test Case -> Test Result (link type: ?)
Test Result -> Bug (link type: Parent)

Note: there's also a Test Case -> Bug link (type: Tests), but when using the 'Copy and add to test suite'-functionality of Test Manager, this can also contain other bugs from the original test cases

Thanks!